# Science fiction short story about a cashless society where they let a guy pay cash but his change is credit

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, anthology-book

I read this story in an anthology of science fiction short stories. I was in grade 6 and it was 1969.

It was about a man that goes to buy something with money but the store was cashless. Finally they sold him the item but had to put what was to be his change on credit.

I can't seem to find it anywhere but it made a huge impression on me and I thought to myself back then that I could see it happening. Lo and behold it is becoming reality.  I thought the name of it was "Yemon."

Comment: Yemon = Yeoman?

Comment: @Valorum I took it to be an anagram of "money". That would fit with the theme of the story.

Comment: Sounds like something Mack Reynolds or Robert Sheckley might write

Comment: There was Lloyd Biggle's "Esidarap Ot Pirt Dnuor", where the couple travelled to a reverse society where stores paid you when you bought something. All the place names were reversed too, so they started off in Kroywen...

Comment: Sounds a bit like one of Cory Doctorow's stories, perhaps Down and Out in the Magic Kingdom?